# How do I make my theme data carry over to a new page in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm building an app in Flutter and I set theme data in the main.dart file. When I navigate to a new page the theme isn't the same and I'm not sure why. I'm fairly new to Flutter and want the theme consistent through the whole app.

This is the code for how I'm navigating pages:

```
 Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (BuildContext context) => JournalYearlyPage(),
                ),
              );
```

Here is my code where I set the Theme in a stateless widget in the main.dart file:

```
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Tasklist App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        primaryColor: Colors.tealAccent,
        primaryColorLight: Colors.lightBlue,
        primaryColorDark: Colors.blueGrey,
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        dividerColor: Colors.teal,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          bodyText1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          subtitle2: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
          subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          headline2: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          headline3: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          headline4: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          headline5: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          headline6: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
      ),
      home: Controller(title: 'tasklist home'),
    );
  }
}
```

Anyone know how to keep my theme data consistent across pages?

Comment: Add where You set the theme please.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if you have another MaterialApp inside your first MaterialApp. The ThemeData is global until you create another MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
  title: "your app name",
  theme: ThemeData(),
  home: someCode(),
);  

someCode(){ 
// this MaterialApp theme will overide the first ones even we didn't mention a new theme attribute (theme: ... )
return MaterialApp(
 home: buildApp()
);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want your theme to apply globally, you need to set it in your main.dart file.

ex:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: "your app name",
  theme: ThemeData(),
);
```

you can find more details here: [theme documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/design/themes)

Comment: I did set the theme in the main.dart file and it was working for my BottomNavigationBar TabController. However, when I used the method described above for "pushing" to a new page the theme changed a little bit. I am unsure why but the background color was different and I don't see a reason for that to be the case.

Comment: without seeing some code, I can only guess. ThemeData set's the colors for all the widgets(dialogs, scaffolds, etc). if the backgroudn changed try to play with ThemeData backgroundColor, scaffoldBackgroundColor, properties.